# c++ Error in tokenizer ''variable 'std::stringstream mystream' has initializer but incomplete type''

Tags: c++, c++11, tokenize

I'm new to c++ and I am trying to read lines from a file with numbers, tokenize lines into string arrays and convert those array items into double precision numbers. But in the process of tokenizing I get this error ''variable 'std::stringstream mystream' has initializer but incomplete type''. I've seen other people suggestions and I want to do it without using boost, and the rest of the codes pretty much look like mine but I get that error for some reason. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<string> tokens;
    string phrase="sdfs sdfs trt we rw";
    stringstream mystream (phrase);
    string temp;

    while(getline(mystream,temp,' ')){
        tokens.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

It would be really nice to get some feedback on this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't include the correct header for [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you are only reading from the string stream, consider using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) instead,

Comment: Lastly, you don't need the loop by the way. All you need is the knowledge of [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and the [`std::vector` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). Notice that vector constructor taking a pair of iterators?

Answer (score 12):

I think you forgot

```
#include <sstream>
```

in your headers.

Answer (score 1):

> "variable 'foo bar' has initializer but incomplete type"

This error means that the variable `bar` has been used in such a way, that the type (`foo`) must be complete. A type that has been merely declared, but not defined is incomplete. So, to make `foo` complete, you must include the definition of `foo`.

In your case, `foo` is `std::stringstream`. You haven't included the definition of `std::stringstream`, so it is not a complete type. In fact, there may not be a guarantee that it has even been declared - it just happens to have been declared by one of the other headers.

Solution: Include the header that defines `std::stringstream`. You can find all headers and what types they define in the standard, which is available as a draft freely online. However, if you don't mind second hand specification, you may find a community maintained c++ reference web site more accessible.